# Why does building ocaml-bin-prot using MacPorts fail?

Tags: ocaml, macports

I am trying to learn `Ocaml` using *Real World Ocaml*. I installed `ocaml` using MacPorts. Now, I am trying to install `ocaml-core-extended`:

```
$ sudo port install ocaml-core-extended
```

but it fails while installing dependency `ocaml-bin-prot`:

Here is the relevant part from the build log:

```
:notice:build --->  Building ocaml-bin-prot
:debug:build Executing org.macports.build (ocaml-bin-prot)
:debug:build Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_ocaml-bin-prot/ocaml-bin-prot/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS' LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.9'
:debug:build Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_ocaml-bin-prot/ocaml-bin-prot/work/bin_prot-108.00.02" && /opt/local/bin/ocaml setup.ml -build'
:debug:build Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_ocaml-bin-prot/ocaml-bin-prot/work/bin_prot-108.00.02" && /opt/local/bin/ocaml setup.ml -build 
:info:build getconf: no such configuration parameter `LFS64_CFLAGS'
:info:build ocamlfind ocamldep -pp 'cpp -traditional -undef -w -DARCH_SIXTYFOUR' -package unix -package bigarray -modules lib/type_class.mli > lib/type_class.mli.depends
:info:build + ocamlfind ocamldep -pp 'cpp -traditional -undef -w -DARCH_SIXTYFOUR' -package unix -package bigarray -modules lib/type_class.mli > lib/type_class.mli.depends
:info:build File "lib/type_class.mli", line 68, characters 16-20:
:info:build Error: Syntax error
:info:build Command exited with code 2.
:info:build E: Failure("Command '/opt/local/bin/ocamlbuild lib/libbin_prot_stubs.a lib/dllbin_prot_stubs.so lib/bin_prot.cma lib/bin_prot.cmxs lib/bin_prot.cmxa lib/bin_prot.a syntax/pa_bin_prot.cma -tag debug' terminated with error code 10")
:info:build Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_ocaml-bin-prot/ocaml-bin-prot/work/bin_prot-108.00.02" && /opt/local/bin/ocaml setup.ml -build 
:info:build Exit code: 1
:error:build org.macports.build for port ocaml-bin-prot returned: command execution failed
```

I looked at the `lib/type_class.mli` and I have no clue why there would be a syntax error there. It is just a macro expansion. I would like my bug report to be a little better than "here's a problem".

So, has anyone encountered this failure? Any hints?

```
 $ uname -a
Darwin zzzz.local 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013;
 root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

```
 $ ocaml -version
The OCaml toplevel, version 4.01.0
```

```
 $ cpp --version
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: @GuyCoder please do not add/create tags that are about a book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the specific problems I had are more related to the transition to Mavericks than anything else.

In the mean time, I decided to install [opam](http://opam.ocaml.org/) with [ocamlbrew](http://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Quick_Install.html#h4-Usingocamlbrew), and everything worked very smoothly.

I was able to set up my environment following the [instructions](https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions).

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of core library? Looks like the library is not updated for OCaml 4.01, probably the port is old and haven't catched up yet..